# General options to avoid nested for-loops for 3d matrix operations

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested, raster

Following my research about nested loops I'd like to put up up this general question: I have to run various functions on 3d-matrices (multi band image files) with a `shape` of e.g. `(2500, 100, 200)` or (bands, rows, cols).

The general (slow) procedure how I approach processing functions looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import time

x = np.random.random_sample([2500, 100, 200])

#  1. & 2. derivative example

def derivate(matrix):
    d1 = np.empty(shape=np.shape(matrix))
    d2 = np.empty(shape=np.shape(matrix))
    for row in range(matrix.shape[1]):
        for col in range(matrix.shape[2]):
            d1[:, row, col] = np.gradient(matrix[:, row, col])
            d2[:, row, col] = np.gradient(d1[:, row, col])
    return d1, d2


t1 = time.perf_counter()
y, z = derivate(x)
t2 = time.perf_counter()
print(t2 - t1)

>>> 4.38 seconds
```

Since many functions in this style already exist in my project environment I am looking for the easiest solution to drastically speed up those nested for-loop functions.

I have seen that many questions here address nested for-loops but I didn't discover any general and transferable solution. 
I would very much appreciate if many available approaches were presented, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement that just like this:

```
import numpy as np

def derivate_vec(matrix):
    d1 = np.gradient(matrix, axis=0)
    d2 = np.gradient(d1, axis=0)
    return d1, d2
```

A quick comparison:

```
import numpy as np
import time

def derivate(matrix):
    d1 = np.empty(shape=np.shape(matrix))
    d2 = np.empty(shape=np.shape(matrix))
    for row in range(matrix.shape[1]):
        for col in range(matrix.shape[2]):
            d1[:, row, col] = np.gradient(matrix[:, row, col])
            d2[:, row, col] = np.gradient(d1[:, row, col])
    return d1, d2

def derivate_vec(matrix):
    d1 = np.gradient(matrix, axis=0)
    d2 = np.gradient(d1, axis=0)
    return d1, d2

# Input data
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.random_sample([2500, 100, 200])

# Check results
d11, d12 = derivate(x)
d21, d22 = derivate_vec(x)
print(np.allclose(d11, d21))
# True
print(np.allclose(d12, d22))
# True

# Measure time
t1 = time.perf_counter()
derivate(x)
t2 = time.perf_counter()
derivate_vec(x)
t3 = time.perf_counter()
print(t2 - t1)
# 3.6777221
print(t3 - t2)
# 0.9414466999999997
```

Comment: Stupid me! I forgot that `np.gradient` has a `axis=` argument. Thanks anyway! What if no such argument exists, if it is a manual, self written function whatsoever.

Comment: @M.Weeker It depends entirely on the particular function. There is no "automagic" way to vectorize a function. There is [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) but, as the documentation states, it's provided for convenience, not performance, as it essentially boils down to a for loop. If you have a loop-based function that cannot be vectorized, then [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org) can usually do a good job accelerating it.

Comment: It already helps alot knowing there is no *magic* solution. Heard of Numba, will give it a try. Thanks man.